# How to draw and fill a triangle with QPainter?

Tags: qt, qpainter

This is what I tried, it gave me no output. Where am I going wrong?

```
      // Start point of bottom line
      qreal startPointX1 = 600.0;
      qreal startPointY1 = 600.0;

      // End point of bottom line          
      qreal endPointX1   = 600.0;
      qreal endPointY1   = 1200.0;

      // Start point of top line
      qreal startPointX2 = 600.0;
      qreal startPointY2 = 600.0;

      // End point of top line          
      qreal endPointX2   = 800.0;
      qreal endPointY2   = 1200.0;


      QPainterPath path;
      // Set pen to this point.
      path.moveTo (startPointX1, startPointY1);
      // Draw line from pen point to this point.
      path.lineTo (endPointX1, endPointY1);

      path.moveTo (endPointX1, endPointY1);
      path.lineTo (endPointX2,   endPointY2);

      path.moveTo (endPointX2,   endPointY2);
      path.lineTo (startPointX1, startPointY1);

      painter.setPen (Qt :: NoPen);
      painter.fillPath (path, QBrush (QColor ("blue")));
```

I have just tried to create a path between these 3 points and fill the area, but there is no output shown.

Comment: did you change any QPainter coordinate transformation matrixes?

Comment: @Nazar554 That is my only code. I didn't do anything besides that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you do not need to call `moveTo()` function after you call `lineTo()` because the current position already updated to the the end point of the line you draw. Here is the code that draws a rectangle for me:

```
// Start point of bottom line
qreal startPointX1 = 600.0;
qreal startPointY1 = 600.0;

// End point of bottom line          
qreal endPointX1   = 600.0;
qreal endPointY1   = 1200.0;

// Start point of top line
qreal startPointX2 = 600.0;
qreal startPointY2 = 600.0;

// End point of top line          
qreal endPointX2   = 800.0;
qreal endPointY2   = 1200.0;

QPainterPath path;
// Set pen to this point.
path.moveTo (startPointX1, startPointY1);
// Draw line from pen point to this point.
path.lineTo (endPointX1, endPointY1);

//path.moveTo (endPointX1, endPointY1); // <- no need to move
path.lineTo (endPointX2,   endPointY2);

//path.moveTo (endPointX2,   endPointY2); // <- no need to move
path.lineTo (startPointX1, startPointY1);

painter.setPen (Qt :: NoPen);
painter.fillPath (path, QBrush (QColor ("blue")));
```

Comment: wow, it works. But `moveTo` was said to be used to move the pen to the point from which we would start drawing a line - so why was I wrong?

Comment: @user462608: you are not wrong, but you needed to do that only once, when you start drawing your rectangle (see the first call of `moveTo()` in the sample code). After you call `lineTo()` position is automatically changes.

Comment: @user462608: that is not true. The docs for `lineTo()` say: `After the line is drawn, the current position is updated to be at the end point of the line.`

Answer (score 11):

If you want use QRectF

```
QRectF rect = QRectF(0, 0, 100, 100);

QPainterPath path;
path.moveTo(rect.left() + (rect.width() / 2), rect.top());
path.lineTo(rect.bottomLeft());
path.lineTo(rect.bottomRight());
path.lineTo(rect.left() + (rect.width() / 2), rect.top());

painter.fillPath(path, QBrush(QColor ("blue")));
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says: "Moving the current point will also start a new subpath (implicitly closing the previously current path when the new one is started)".

This means you should once move to the origin of the path, then use only lineTo in order to draw the shape to be filled.

I added this answer because the answer "I think you do not need to call moveTo() function after you call lineTo() because the current position already updated to the the end point of the line you draw." is quite misleading. The moveTo is not unnecessary, it's actually causing the problem.