# How to fill a triangle in a map canvas with color? Qgis 3.3

Tags: c++, qt, qgis

I have 3 points (QPointF) and a QgsRubberBand(PolygonGeometry) in which I added these 3 points. The result is as in the image

[image]

The triangle has very thin white lines. I want to fill the triangle with a color. I was expecting setFillColor() method to do it but it doesn't. What can I do to fill the polygon with a given color?

The rubberband was declared in the class constructor as:

> cameraFOV = new QgsRubberBand(mapCanvas,
>   QgsWkbTypes::PolygonGeometry);

Here is the code I used to display the triangle:

```
void MapObject::setFovAngle(double angle){
    cameraFOV->reset();
    QPointF FOVLeftCorner = QPointF(mapOwnPosition.x() + 5000 * qSin(targetingDirection-angle/2), mapOwnPosition.y() + 5000 * qCos(targetingDirection-angle/2));
    QPointF FOVRightCorner = QPointF(mapOwnPosition.x() + 5000 * qSin(targetingDirection+angle/2), mapOwnPosition.y() + 5000 * qCos(targetingDirection+angle/2));
    cameraFOV->addPoint(mapOwnPosition);
    cameraFOV->addPoint(FOVLeftCorner);
    cameraFOV->addPoint(FOVRightCorner);
    cameraFOV->closePoints();
    cameraFOV->setColor(QColor(255,255,255, 128));
    cameraFOV->setFillColor(QColor(0,0,0, 128));
    cameraFOV->show();
}
```

What can I do to fill the triangle with a color?

Comment: This might be useful, here's a link to someone creating a triangle using coordinates like you have there.

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356747/how-to-draw-and-fill-a-triangle-with-qpainter)

Comment: Thank you JComputerScience for your research. I now need to know how to attach a QPainter to a QgsMapCanvas.